# WebBrowser control never fires DocumentCompleted event

Tags: c#, .net

I have a following code inside windows forms application but `web_DocumentCompleted` event never fires on my windows 10 machine

What's bothering me is that the same code works just fine if I compile it and run it on my VPS (windows server 2012R2), or machine which has windows 8.1 installed.

All machines have Internet Explorer 11 installed.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Web Browser control
    this.web.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(web_DocumentCompleted);

    this.web.Navigate(URL);
}

void web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //or any other code
     MessageBox.Show("Done");  

}
```

I have tried to remove update KB3132372 as suggested on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540624/webbrowser-control-crashes-on-windows-10), but it did not help.

Why does this code works fine on windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012, but it does not work on two separate windows 10 machines?

Comment: If you want to see output from Console.WriteLine() then you'll have to enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process option.  Do favor the debugger instead.

Comment: I'll modify my question a bit.It does not work if i put any code in there.

Comment: Shouldn't that code be in the Load event?  The handle hasn't been created yet in the constructor.

Comment: code works just fine except on windows 10 machines

Comment: Hmm, I get an InvalidOperationException running your code: "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.".  Visual Studio 2012, .Net 4.5, Windows 10.

Comment: @LarsTech have you added WebBrowser control to your form?

Comment: Yeah, it's the only control on the form.

Comment: try just `this.web.Navigate(URL);` instead of using invoke and delegate. I've updated code in my question.

Comment: That works, and I was expecting it to.  The DocumentCompleted event fires, too.

Comment: That's odd. Works for me too on win 8.1 and win server, but not win 10. Have you upgraded your previous OS to win 10 or made a fresh installation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107271/discussion-between-robert-and-larstech).

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue. DocumentCompleted Event is never called when ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete.

The issue I have is that the "Document.Body.KeyDown" event cannot be called unless the Body is created. It is created of course when the document is completed.

The hack I found is to create a while loop and execute a "Application.DoEvents()" until the "ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete". Right after that you can be certain that the Document has been completed.